# jQuery get next textbox in table not in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

How do I get the next available textbox from a table if there are rows in between that do not have a textbox? I have datepicker, that once the date has been selected, will have to automatically enable the next available textbox.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan=2>HEAD</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td><td><input type=text name=a1 id=a1 class=dp></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td><td><input type=text name=a2 id=a2 class=dp></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>HEAD2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td><td><input type=text name=a3 id=a3 class=dp></td></tr>
<tr><td>Item</td><td><input type=text name=a4 id=a4 class=dp></td></tr>
```

Item

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dp").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function () {
            // Activate next  textbox and focus on it for further editing
            var el = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input').prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabled");
            // Trigger change as when using this event it overrides element onchange and we have to force the event to fire
            $(this).trigger("change");
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine but only for the first of the consecutive textboxes (id's a1, a3). It will not work on id=a2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` of the collection of datepickers to target the next in collection using `eq()`

```
// store collection of inputs if collection is static, saves additional DOM searches
var $datepickers = $(".dp").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onSelect: function() {
  // get current index
    var currIndex = $datepickers.index(this);
    // target next in collection
    $datepickers.eq(currIndex + 1).prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabled");
    // Trigger change as when using this event it overrides element onchange and we have to force the event to fire
    $(this).trigger("change");
  }
});
```

Note would need to build collection inside callback if you are dynamically adding rows

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), `:has()` , `:first`

```
var el = $(this).closest('tr')
        .nextAll(":has(input):first")
        .find('input')
        .prop("disabled", false)
        .removeClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dp").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function() {
      // Activate next  textbox and focus on it for further editing
      var $els = $(this).closest('table').find('input');
      var cur = $els.index($(this));
      var $next = $els.eq(cur+1);
      $next.prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabled").focus();
      // Trigger change as when using this event it overrides element onchange and we have to force the event to fire
      $(this).trigger("change");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>HEAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>
      <input type=text name=a1 id=a1 class=dp>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>
      <input type=text name=a2 id=a2 class=dp>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>HEAD2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>
      <input type=text name=a3 id=a3 class=dp>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>
      <input type=text name=a4 id=a4 class=dp>
    </td>
  </tr>
```